# How to grant access only to assets files using apache2?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Have a assets folder with css, js, images, etc. How to allow access to all for get specific extensions files like png, css, etc? but deny all others, using the htaccess?.

The assets folder is dinamic, by example:

```
/.htaccess
/foo/assets/
/bar/assets/
```

I try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+?/assets/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js)$
RewriteRule . /403.php [L]
```

But does not work, i can access to `/foo/assets/css/evil.php`.

Comment: Your implementation i a bit complicated... Why two conditions, why not put all in a single pattern for the actual rule? Certainly possible too...

Comment: Could it be that your dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") does not get considered by the http server? How did you make sure it _is_ read and evaluated?

Comment: The assets folder are uploaded by external users for example CDN, but the web server is apache with php module, is dangerous, or html files. I do not want install other apache in other web server only for storage the static files. If upload the .htaccess into assets folder, the users can delete this.

Comment: I have solved the problem using the apache virtualhost config with the `Directory` directive and `Files` with `order allow,deny`.

Comment: I fail to see what the fact how things get uploaded has to do with what I suggested. But anyway, fine that you found a solution.